# How to fix INET error "Cannot load library"

Tags: ubuntu, omnet++, inet

I am using OMNeT++ 5.5.1 and INET 4 in ubuntu 18.04. It was working fine.
I copied some folders/files from other machine (done in ubuntu 19.04 with exactly the same OMNeT++ and INET version) to inet, and then rebuild inet successfully.

But the problem is when i am trying to run sensornetwork/omnetpp.ini, it is giving the following errors.
Would anyone please suggest how to fix it? Thanks

```
<!> Error: Cannot load library '../../../src//libINET.so': ../../../src//libINET.so: undefined symbol: _ZN4inet8Protocol8smartmacE

End.

Simulation terminated with exit code: 1
Working directory: /home/tech/Downloads/inet4/showcases/wireless/sensornetwork
Command line: opp_run -m -n ../../../src:../../../examples:../../../tutorials:../.. --image-path=../../../images -l ../../../src/INET omnetpp.ini

Environment variables:
PATH=/home/tech/Downloads/omnetpp-5.5.1/bin::/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/tech/Downloads/omnetpp-5.5.1/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/tech/Downloads/omnetpp-5.5.1/lib::/home/tech/Downloads/inet4/src:
OMNETPP_IMAGE_PATH=/home/tech/Downloads/omnetpp-5.5.1/images
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to run `make cleanall`, then `make makefiles` and then rebuild the whole INET project. This is a linker error, and looks like some object files were not linked in correctly. Specifically this could happen if the Makefile is not re-created after you add additional `.cc` files to a project. (you did not specify what file you have copied from the other machine, but if you have copied `.cc` files, then the above can happen).

TIP: You have to re-create the make files **each time** you add new source files to your project (the IDE, does it for you, but on the command line, you must do it manually)